# How can I delete a file that doesn't exist from Sourcetree with a new line character "\n"?

Tags: git, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, atlassian-sourcetree

In Unity, I clicked on a file to rename it and pasted a name that had extra white spaces spaces in it. This caused my last commit to save a file that looks something like this: "public interface IMyInterface\n.cs

This '\n' character is causing Sourcetree to not be able to find the file and keeps giving me a 'file does not exist' error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a file in the source tree with a newline character in the path. If so, this will work:

Get a linux machine

Clone to the linux machine

delete the file

commit the change

push

Comment: will this work if I use a ubuntu on a virtual box?

Comment: @LuneTech: Yes.

Comment: Give WSL a try first.